# Change opacity of image in CSS

Tags: css, splash-screen, opacity

How do I animated the image's opacity from 0.5 to 1? I am making a splash screen and I want my website to change when the image's opacity reaches 1.
This is my code:

```css
.preload{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class = "preload" id="preload">
  <div class ="logo">
    <img src = "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/5.sm.jpg" class = "logo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE]?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "I want my website to change when the image's opacity reach 1"?

Comment: @Dialex Hi, what I meant was this html is splash screen,  and it will navigate to my home page when the opacity reach 1

Comment: @aloisdg Hi, sorry but I am new to coding. I have no idea of what you're saying.

Comment: Ok, I understood what you meant. Look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CSS Animation**

```
.preload{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;}
.logo {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0.5;
    animation: fadeIn 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `animation` properties. Try this:

```css
.preload{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  animation: example 3s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes example {
  0%   {opacity: 0.0;}
  25%  {opacity: 0.25;}
  50%  {opacity: 0.50;}
  75%  {opacity: 0.75;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div class = "preload" id="preload">
  <div class ="logo">
    <img src = "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/5.sm.jpg" class = "logo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hihi, I did it, thanks anyway, I tried your method, it works too!

Comment: Glad to know you did it yourself. Keep it up. :)